# Quickly save databases from a template to my new project while preserving the symbology

Tags: arcgis-pro, template

I am trying to create a template with several maps, layouts, and datasets pre-loaded. Some of the datasets will include data that I will not modify, but others will be empty datasets, with the symbology set to my preferences. I plan to add features to those datasets using the create new feature tool. This will save me the time of creating each feature class and setting the symbology to my liking.

Once I use the template to create a new project and all the features are loaded, if I start creating new features in these feature classes, will be overwriting data that is used in other projects? How can I ensure that the modifications I make to each feature class will stay with the project I am working within and not affect other projects? Do I just need to copy the datasets that I plan to edit into the home geodatabase file for the new project I just created?

Comment: Just edited it. Is this better now?

Comment: In which database (or workspace) are the blank data sets (feature classes)?  Where are you creating the new features?   Have you tried it?  Do the data sets get overwritten?

Comment: This is the first time I have made a project template so I am not sure if I am doing it correctly. To make the template, I opened a project, then went to Share -> Project Template. Checked save template to file, and saved it in my ProjectTemplates folder. So the datasets are in the .gdb associated with the project that I used to create the template. I recently migrated from ArcMap and am still learning to use the gdb files, and the file organization thing in ArcGis Pro is still very confusing to me.

Comment: I guess my question could be, if I create a new project using a template and the filepath for the home geodatabase becomes C:\Users\User\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\New_Project\Database.gdb, is Database.gdb still associated with the project that I used to create the template (Old_Project) or is it uniquely associated with New_Project?

Comment: It should be associated with the new project, and therefore I don't think the problem exists.  It's easy to test though.  Why don't you just try it and see?